# how to use raycast to check wall collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]I have these movement controls, and it worked very well, but there's one problem which is the player can go through the walls.
I searched for it, and I found that the raycast would solve it, but I didn't know how to implement it.
How can I use (raycast) to prevent the player from moving through the wall?

```
 private void Update()
    {
          if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && !isMoving)
                StartCoroutine(MovePlayer(Vector3.up));

          if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && !isMoving)
              StartCoroutine(MovePlayer(Vector3.left));

          if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow) && !isMoving)
              StartCoroutine(MovePlayer(Vector3.down));

          if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow) && !isMoving)
              StartCoroutine(MovePlayer(Vector3.right));
}

private IEnumerator MovePlayer(Vector3 direction)
    {
        isMoving = true;
        float elapsedTime = 0;
        origPos = transform.position;
        targetPos = origPos + direction;

        while(elapsedTime < timeToMove)
        {
           transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(origPos, targetPos, (elapsedTime / timeToMove));
            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }

        transform.position = targetPos;

        isMoving = false;
    }
```

Comment: May I ask what kind of movement you're trying to replicate? Usually speaking the best way is to add force instead of changing the actual position. Which there from, all you have to make sure is that there's colliders on the things u want to walk on, and a rigidbody on the player. This would immediately solve your problem. But if this is not the case, you'd most likely have to shoot a raycast from the player in each direction, if the raycast hits something which would hold a tag "Wall" you could calculate the length  of that, if its smaller than a certain treshold, dont allow the player to move

Comment: in that direction, you can get the opposite position of the original hit and reflect ur code based on that. I'd recommend just sticking with Unity's physics engine for now though. As you can see, using raycast complicates quite some things.

Comment: How to use raycast is documented well in the unity docs. Pleas be more specific as to what you have a problem with

Answer (score 0):

Raycast is a heavy task in unity, which can make your game delay

But if you want to research about it, I can have a simple example for you to let you know how raycast work

A raycast, according to my opinion, is a ray which can be started at one position, have a direction, length and can detect which gameobject collide with it, as long as that game object have "collider". You can find more at Unity documentation

So, back to your questions, the raycast can be shot from your position, follow your direction and the length of the raycast will be calculated so that it can detect the wall. It is possible, yeah. But you have to check it frequently, right, each time you move to another position.

I see another problem in your code is that you are using transform to move your gameobject. If you use transform, it means that you will teleport from your distance to another distance. If the wall is not thick enough, you may teleport to the position that is behind the wall

I suggest using Addforce, add collider to the wall, your player. Add rigidbody to your player and put Addforce in FixedUpdate() in unity